# Counting and finding real solutions of an equation

Tags: equation-solving

I have two functions:

```
f[x_] := Sin[x^2] + Sin[x]^2
g[x_] := Exp[(5 - x)^2/10]
```

[image]
Now I am trying to count the number of real solutions to f(x) = g(x) and find those roots. I tried

```
eqn = f[x] - g[x] == 0;
CountRoots[eqn, x]
roots = NSolve[eqn, x, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 80]
```

However, I'm not able to get any results. It returns `CountRoots::nuniv: True is not a univariate function of x.` How can I count and find the real roots of that equation? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should just do `CountRoots[f[x] - g[x], x]` without the `== 0` . This still won't work though: _Unable to compute the number of roots with the available methods_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
 CountRoots[Sin[x^2] + Sin[x]^2 - Exp[(5 - x)^2/10], {x, 3, 8}]
    
    (*  10  *)
    
   lst = FindRoot[
    Sin[x^2] + Sin[x]^2 - Exp[(5 - x)^2/10] == 0, {x, #}] & /@ {3.5, 
   4, 4.2, 4.9, 5, 5.2, 5.7, 5.9, 7.1, 7.3}

(* {{x -> 3.70039}, {x -> 3.86421}, {x -> 3.70039}, {x -> 4.68837}, {x ->
    5.02256}, {x -> 5.28816}, {x -> 5.67646}, {x -> 5.79265}, {x -> 
   7.19249}, {x -> 7.2094}}  *)

lst // Length

(* 10 *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] := Sin[x^2] + Sin[x]^2
g[x_] := Exp[(5 - x)^2/10]

eqn = f[x] - g[x] == 0;
```

As shown by Alexei, with [`CountRoots`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CountRoots.html), specify an interval of interest

```
nbrRoots = CountRoots[eqn[[1]], {x, 0, 8}]

(* 10 *)
```

Again specifying an interval, and using [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html), the exact real roots are given as [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expressions

```
roots = Solve[{eqn, 0 < x < 8}, x, Reals]
```

[image]

Their approximate numeric values are

```
roots // N[#, 10] & (* specify desired precision *)

(* {{x -> 3.700390723}, {x -> 3.864212527}, {x -> 4.360167327}, {x -> 
   4.688369968}, {x -> 5.022557762}, {x -> 5.288157488}, {x -> 
   5.676460879}, {x -> 5.792653949}, {x -> 7.192494025}, {x -> 7.209401757}} *)

nbrRoots == Length@roots

(* True *)

Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 8},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.6, .7}],
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{x, f[x]} /. roots]}]
```

[image]